# Grep for two digit numbes with Perl style syntax

Tags: regex, perl, grep

So I am going through O'Reilly's Regular Expression Pocket Reference.

I found the example:

```
/^\d{1,6}$/
```

Which is supposed to match any 1-6 digit number.

However, when I attempt to run it through grep with PCRE syntax on Ubuntu it only matches *1* digit numbers.

I run it this way:

```
grep -P "^\d{1,6}^" *
```

So I gave it a shot in Perl, and it seems to work as intended:

```
$example = 600; 

if($example =~ /^\d{1,6}^/){
     print "Gotcha! \n"; # fires as it should 
} else { 
     print "failed \n"; #doesn't fire
} 

$counterexample = 6000000000000000000000; 

if($counterexample =~ /^d{1,6}$/{ 
     print "This shouldn't be \n"; # does not fire, as intended
} else { 
     print "also correct \n"; # Fires as intended 
}
```

So, shouldn't grep behave the same way with the -P flag?

I'm sure I'm missing something essential here.

**Update**

Corrected second `^` to `$`

```
grep -P "^\d{1,6}$" *
```

I notice that it seems to work on files like

```
//example file.txt works as intended 
12
123
12345
1234567

//but this doesn't work 
600 500 20 

// Just matches the first one
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works fine:

```
$ cat > 'test'
qwer
1234
1234567
12
qwer
^C
$ grep -P "^\d{1,6}$" *
test:1234
test:12
```

Was your use of a second `^` a mistype, or did you actually intend to use that instead of a `$`?

**Update**

Why would it match the new example? `600 500 20`

There are spaces between those numbers and the regex you use is bounded by the anchors `^` and `$` for the start and end of a line.  If you wanted those numbers to match, you'd have to use the word boundary anchors instead.  `/\b\d{1,6}\b/`

In other words, your regex is functioning as intended.

Comment: Was a mistype. Tried with your example, and it worked. Edited the question

Comment: Updated for your change to the question.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense to me now.